# Selected rows of the DataGridView reset after load of dialog

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have one dialog, which based on `System.Windows.Forms.Form`. It contains one control `DataGridView`.
I fill this `DataGridView`, and select any rows. Later call I the method `ShowDialog` of my form. After appear of form I can see that selected first row of `DataGridView`, but my desired rows are not selected. How can I resolve this problem? I want no make select in the method `OnLoad`

Below is my code.

> ```
> DgvDataSource dgvDs = new DgvDataSource(); 
> DgvForm dgvF = new DgvForm();
>
> dgvF.DataSource = dgvDs; 
> dgvF.SelectRows(new int[] { 3, 5, 7, 9, 10}); dgvF.ShowDialog();
>
>  public class DgvForm : Form 
>  {
>     public DgvForm()
>     {
>         InitializeComponent();
>     }
>
>     DgvDataSource dataSource;
>     public DgvDataSource DataSource
>     {
>         get { return myDataGridView.DataSource; }
>         set
>         {
>             myDataGridView.DataSource = value;
>         }
>     }
>
>     public void SelectRows(int[] indexes)
>     {
>         myDataGridView.ClearSelection();
>         foreach (DataGridViewRow r in dataGridView1.Rows)
>         {
>             r.Cells[0].Selected = indexes.Contains(r.Index);
>         }
>
>     } 
> }
>
> public class DgvDataSource
> {
>     public BindingList<DgvItem> Items { get; private set; }
>
>     public DgvDataSource()
>     {
>         InitItems();
>     }
>
>     void InitItems()
>     {
>         Items = new BindingList<DgvItem>();
>         for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
>         {
>             Items.Add(new DgvItem() { Id = i + 1, 
>                                         Description = "Description " + (i+1).ToString() });
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> public class DgvItem
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string Description { get; set; }
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Put you SelectRows in the Load Event in the Dialog Form. When you create the instance, set a int[] property:

```
 DgvForm dgvF = new DgvForm();
 //this property should be in the Dialog Form 
 dgvF.Selection = new int[] { 3, 5, 7, 9, 10}; 
 dgvF.ShowDialog();
```

Luego en el Form:

```
private int[] selection;

public int[] Selection
{
get { return selection; }
set { selection = value; }
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//Put your code here, to load DataSource and Select Rows.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. But unfortunately it is not suitable. That is the same as make the selection in overrided method OnLoad (I have say, I said that this solution is not very suitable)